# Not able to specify the cidr for pods for EKS Installation

Tags: amazon-eks

The current default cidr block in EKS for the Pods is clashing with Subnet cidr block. Any place where we can mention the cidr blocks in the cloud formation template.

Is it true that the pods becomes part of the same network as the worker nodes .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html 
This will create lot of problem as the ips will get exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add subnets for your worker nodes to the EKS cluster with [SubnetIds under EKS Cluster ResourcesVpcConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-eks-cluster-resourcesvpcconfig.html). This currently requires a recreation of the cluster!

Yes, the pods use the same subnet as the node they are being scheduled on. Consider larger CIDR blocks (/22 and above) for EKS subnets. Kubernetes may place pods that will get stuck in `ContainerCreating` due to no available IP addresses in the subnet.

Update:
[With CNI Custom Networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-custom-network.html), you can have pods use different subnets.